# TypeError: argument 1 must have a "write" method -- creating csv from dict

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

I'm trying to create a csv from a dict, but I'm receiving the error:

```
in create_csv
    writer = csv.writer('userInfo.csv')
TypeError: argument 1 must have a "write" method
```

Code:

```
#Create dict file to test
userInfoDict = {'orgID': '17', 'firstName': 'TestFirstName', 'lastName': 'TesLastName',
                'emailAddress': 'test@test.com', 'phoneNumber': '123-456-7890',
                'isoCountryCode': 'US'}

def create_csv(userInfoDict):
    import csv

    userInfo = open('userInfo.csv', 'wb')

    for key in userInfoDict:
        if len(userInfoDict['orgID']) == 0:
            print('Not a valid user: No orgID')
            return None
        elif len(userInfoDict['firstName']) == 0:
            print('Not a valid user: No First Name')
            return None
        elif len(userInfoDict['emailAddress']) == 0 or len(userInfoDict['phoneNumber']) == 0:
            print('Not a valid user: No Email or Phone')
            return None
        else:
            writer = csv.writer(userInfo, delimiter=',')
            for key, value in userInfoDict.items():
                writer.writerow([key], [value])
        return

create_csv(userInfoDict)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should pass your file but not the file name to the writer:

```
with open('userInfo.csv', 'wb') as userInfoCsv:
    writer = csv.writer(userInfoCsv)
```

2. You should not have the '.' symbol in the name of your variable, so you variable should be `userInfoCsv` or `user_info_csv`
3. `userInfo = open('userInfo.csv', 'wb')` why you use this line? You open your file later using `with open('userInfo.csv', 'wb')`
4. You could see a method `csv.DictWriter`

   ```
   with open('userInfo.csv', 'wb') as user_info_csv:
       writer = csv.DictWriter(user_info_csv, fieldnames=['your', 'column', 'names'], delimiter=';')
       writer.writerow(userInfoDict)
   ```

**UPDATE**
full code of function with updates from comments

```
def create_csv(userInfoDict):
    import csv

    with open('userInfo.csv', 'wb') as userInfo:

        for key in userInfoDict:
            if len(userInfoDict['orgID']) == 0:
                print('Not a valid user: No orgID')
                return None
            elif len(userInfoDict['firstName']) == 0:
                print('Not a valid user: No First Name')
                return None
            elif len(userInfoDict['emailAddress']) == 0 or len(userInfoDict['phoneNumber']) == 0:
                print('Not a valid user: No Email or Phone')
                return None
            else:
                writer = csv.DictWriter(userInfo, fieldnames=userInfoDict.keys(), delimiter=';')
                # writer.writeheader()  # If you want to add header
                writer.writerow(userInfoDict)
```

Comment: Changed code to match your fix, and it didn't seem to have any effect.  Same error.  in create_csv
    writer = csv.writer('userInfocsv')
TypeError: argument 1 must have a "write" method

Comment: Of course the `open` should happen before the loop. As it is each loop cycle will open the file again and overwrite the previous content.

Comment: @Matthias sure, so there is not sense to use with statement

Comment: @Eric YOu should delete quotes. csv.writer(userInfocsv) not csv.writer('userInfocsv')

Comment: Probably want to use a dialect as well; at least pass `delimeter` to `writer()`.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I've updated my code to match your suggestions, and it's cleared the error. However I'm receiving the error "in create_csv
    writer.writerow([key], [value])
TypeError: writerow() takes exactly one argument (2 given)"

Comment: @Eric you could use the last version.